# No video on Mac Mini over HDMI

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, macintosh, hdmi

I would like to install Elementary (Loki) on to my Mac Mini (7,1).  I can boot from the USB installer however after the bootloader I get no video.  I doesn't matter if I select to try without installing, to install, to install OEM, the screen (in this case a 60 inch TV) goes black and never returns.  The boot loader displays perfectly and at a full 1080.

There is no adapter or anything, I am just connected via an HDMI cable from the HDMI port on the Mac Mini to the back of the TV.

Comment: Have you installed drivers for hdmi?

Comment: How would I install drivers for HDMI?  Elementary is not installed and as detailed above cannot be installed as after any selection from the boot loader on the USB stick there is no more video.

Comment: I would check the Ubuntu community, most of it also applies to Elementary OS, like: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbumtuOnMacMini
Maybe, if you have the required dongles, try anther connection, like dvi or vga?

Answer (score 1):

So the thing that worked was simply unplugging the HDMI cable and plugging it back in, I have to do this after every reboot, it's a bit annoying but manageable.